# Changed code from foundation to bootstrap now my entire form is not clickable, what gives?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

If you need more info please do not down vote! I am new to this site and would like to get better at asking these questions. I update quickly. Thanks in advance!

This is probably a silly mistake on my part. I believe it was working before, all i had done was change my styling from foundation to bootstrap and now some of my React components do not work properly. Here's a couple snippets of the afflicted code. I'm hoping I can get a few ideas as to what happened.
this is my text area

```
import React from 'react';

import { ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap'

const CheckField = (props) => {
  return(
  <div>
    <ControlLabel>{props.label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        name={props.body}
        type='text'
        onChange={props.handlerFunction}
        value={props.content}
      />
      <FormControl.Feedback />
  </div>
    );
  }

  export default CheckField;
```

This is my Form

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import CheckField from '../components/CheckField'
     import ArrowContainer from './ArrowContainer'
     import { FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
     import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap'

    class FormContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        errors: {},
        checkConsumed: '',
        check: ''
      }
        this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckChange = this.handleCheckChange.bind(this);
        this.validateCheck = this.validateCheck.bind(this);
      }


      // componentDidMount() {
      //   this.loadReviewsFromServer();
      //   setInterval(this.loadReviewsFromServer.bind(this), this.props.pollInterval);
      // }

        // setInterval(clickHandler)
        // {this.props.onClick, this.state.actualTimeSelected)};

      handleClearForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          errors: {},
          checkConsumed: '',
          check: ''
        })
      }
      handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        {
          let formPayload = {
            check: this.state.checkConsumed,
            category_id: this.props.categoryId
          };
          if (this.validateCheck(formPayload.check)){

            this.props.addNewReality(formPayload);
            this.handleClearForm(event);
          }

        }
      }
      handleCheckChange(event) {
        this.setState({ checkConsumed: event.target.value })
      }

      validateCheck(check) {
        if (check === '') {
          let newError = { check: 'You must write a check.' }
          this.setState({ errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, newError) })
          return false
        } else {
          let errorState = this.state.errors
          delete errorState.handleFormSubmit
          this.setState({ errors: errorState })
          return true
        }
      }
  render() {
    let errorDiv;
    let errorItems;
    if (Object.keys(this.state.errors).length > 1) {
      errorItems = Object.values(this.state.errors).map(error => {
        return(<li key={error}>{error}</li>)
      })
      errorDiv = <div className="callout alert">{errorItems}</div>
    }
  return (
      <div>
        <FormGroup className="callout reactform col-xs-2 col-sm-8 `col-md-4 col-lg-12 " onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>`
        {errorDiv}
        <div className="reality input">
          <CheckField className="reality input"
            content={this.state.checkConsumed}
            label='Create Question Quote or Statement for the Database!'
            name='check'
            placeholder="realities"
            type="text"
            id="reality"
            handlerFunction={this.handleCheckChange}
          />
        </div>
          <div className="button-group expanded react-buttons">
            <button className="button large" id="clear" onClick={this.handleClearForm}>Clear</button>
            <input className="button large" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            <button className="reload success button" >
              <a className="reload" href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Reload Realities to see yours!</a>
            </button>
          </div>
        </FormGroup>
        <div className= "animated SlideInLeft arrow">
          <
          ArrowContainer
          user_id = {this.props.user}
          categoryId = {this.props.categoryId}
          checkConsumed = {this.props.checkConsumed}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default FormContainer;
```

Comment: Have you inspected using dev tools?  Perhaps an element is covering your form elements and preventing clicks.

Comment: I actually have not considered that. From what i can see nothing looks bad but can i take a picture of what i see in the console and update my post with it? I might not see this issue if it is happening

Comment: I have another react component that works finei figured i must have done something weird while editing it for bootstrap

Comment: actually i realized it works but only on certain screen sizes. How can that be possible????

Answer (score 0):

So after a few suggestions from colleagues I looked into the CSS that was targeting the container i was having issues with. Actually, I just deleted it. And now it works. Basically CSS is rude sometimes and doesn't play nice. Hope this helps someone one day.